# Аналог базы данных в объектах

Tags: java, база-данных

Дали задание написать консольное приложение, база студентов, не используя баз данных, а только объекты для хранения.
В чем суть задания.Пользователь должен ввести сначала институт, далее кафедры, потом предметы. Причем институт один, а кафедры естественно несколько, так же и не сколько предметов ну это логично в принципе. И далее идет регистрация студента водится его ФИО идет выбор института кафедры. Институтов в приложении может быть не сколько, так как считается что мы пишем для университета.
И далее будет выбор заполнение баллов для студента (поиск будет изначально при выборе института, кафедры, группы, потом поиск по фИО).

> ```
> Приблизительное меню
> 0.Добавить институт
> 1.Добавить студента
> 3.Заполнение баллов
> 4.Изменить данные студента(ред. баллов, может группы)
> 5.Вывести весь список
>
> select 0
> Ведите институт : 
> а
> Ведите кафедры : 
> в
> Exit ? y 
> в
> Exit ? y 
> Ведите предметы :
> в
> Exit ? y 
> в
> Exit ? y 
> select 1
> Выберите институт : 
> 1 - a
> 2 - какой то другой
> 1
> Выберите кафедру : 
> 1 - и
> 2 - какой то другой
> 2
> Ведите группу  : 
> 179
> Ведите ФИО : Иван И.И.
>
> select 5 (пример списка)
> Институт компьютерной науки | Кафедра системного анализа
> Группа - 134
> ФИО         Высшая математика  Программирование  
> Иванов и.и.         80               75
>
> Институт компьютерной науки | Кафедра системных наук
> Группа - 144
> ФИО         Высшая математика  Программирование  
> Иванов и.и.         80               75
> ```

**Вот в основном в чем заключается вопрос, как мне связать институт кафедры и предметы.**

Думал сделать массив объектов

```
Inst[] inst = new Inst[100];
Pulpit[] pul = new Pulpit[100];
Subjects[] sub = new Subjects[100];
```

Но как мне их связать, может я совсем не так представляю архитектуру приложение.
Прошу помочь.

Думал делать так записать в массив обьектов  `Inst[] inst`, массив обьектов   `Pulpit[] pul = new Pulpit[100];` и так далее но понимаю это совсем не верно.

Answer (score 0):

Хоть в задании указано не использовать базы данных - советую все таки хотя бы поверхностно их работу изучить. За последние 50 лет в работе реляционных баз данных ничего кардинально не менялось, вряд ли вы придумаете что-то новое =) С нереляционными чуть поинтереснее история, но все равно вероятность, что вы изобретете вместо велосипеда ионный двигатель весьма мала

Суть в том, что вам следует использовать логику бд. Если говорим про реляционные бд - для каждого класса объектов заводим некий id, который уникален в рамках класса. То есть среди всех предметов нет двух, у которых id совпадает. Нет двух факультетов, у которых id совпадает и т.п. Теперь чтобы указать, что предмет А есть на факультете Б, то

1. если предмет может быть только в одном факультете, то просто в
   описании предмета делаем поле dep_id, в котором указывается id нужного факультета
2. если предмет может быть на нескольких факультетах, то создаем мапу, в которой храним пары id факультета-id предмета

Альтернативный вариант, а-ля нереляционные бд. создается объект класса институт. Внутри него создается поле, содержащие список объектов класса факультет. Внутри каждого факультета  создается поле, содержащее список предметов и т.д. Но с таким подходом возникают сложности в поддержании консистентности в случае дублирования.

Можете комбинировать подходы. И никогда, ни при каких обстоятельствах, ни в коем случае, ни за что, вообще никогда не используйте массивы фиксированной длины, когда эта длина не фиксирована. ArrayList вам в помощь